# Exception while loading Webpage Primefaces

Tags: web, primefaces, nosuchmethoderror

When I try to load my Webpage, I'm getting the following exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext.(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)V

I tried to figure out where it's coming from, but I couldn't find out anything :(
Have you ever encountered this exception and know how to resolve it?

Here is the full stack-trace from Glassfish:

```
WARNUNG: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext.<init>(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)V
at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.<init>(PrimeFacesContext.java:16)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContextFactory.getFacesContext(PrimeFacesContextFactory.java:23)
at com.sun.faces.context.InjectionFacesContextFactory.getFacesContext(InjectionFacesContextFactory.java:121)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:583)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[/code]
```

Thanks in advance
Xera

Comment: Are you using Morjarra or Myfaces and did you include Primefaces jar file to your project ?

Comment: You might have multiple different versioned PrimeFaces JAR files in your webapp's runtime classpath.

Comment: thank you RongNK that was actually the problem :-) we had two different versions of primefaces in our classpath. thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, you should post as answer to close your question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RongNK suggested correctly, we had multiply versions of PrimeFaces in our classpath which cause this error. Thank you again RongNK :)

Answer (score 0):

i received a similar Error from an @ManagedBean

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: package.ManagedBean.

But the ManagedBean provides a method public init() {...}

so here is what worked for me: 
Just implement an public constructor without parameters for the error-class.